# Sphere Detection in Point Cloud using PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have captured a point cloud of a scene in which a ball is mounted on a robotic arm. The Ball is rigid and having the diameter approximately 150 mm. Below is the screenshot of Point Cloud-

[image]

In order to track the ball (orange color in above screenshot), I tried to use Sample Consensus Initial Alignment (SAC-IA) algorithm, hence I first made a template, which is the point cloud of ball using following code-

```
typedef pcl::PointXYZRGB Point;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<Point> PointCloud;

PointCloud sphere;

float r = 0.075; // in meters
for(float phi = 0;  phi < 2* M_PI; phi+=0.01)
{
  float z = r * cos(phi);
  for(float th = 0;  th < M_PI; th+=0.01)
  {
    float x = r * sin(phi) * cos(th);
    float y = r * sin(phi) * sin(th);

    Point point;
    point.x = x; point.y = y; point.z = z;  // position
    point.b = 51; point.g = 87; point.r = 255; // color

    sphere.push_back(point);
  }
}
sphere.is_dense = true;
sphere.height = 1;
sphere.width = sphere.points.size();
```

The template is then matched with point cloud using the code provided in [official PCL website here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/template_alignment.php). I am not putting the code here since it is too long (approximately 300 lines).

Below is the screenshot of the detection, in which I painted a green sphere in detected location-

[image]

Clearly, the **ball detection has failed**. Below are my queries-

1. How to make it working? Any fine-tuning of parameters?
2. Is there any better approach for sphere detection in PCL?

Comment: Could you share the point cloud???

Comment: This is just a quick guess but have you considered that the template sphere you are generating is bigger than the sphere you are trying to find??. Maybe if you adjust the size of the template you could get the aligment you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked it and concluded few interesting points. the captured point cloud data doesn't contain sufficient information to detect sphere. The sphere in the point cloud is too noisy to detect. However, if I capture the point cloud with a bigger sphere, the detection is possible. Also depending on the point cloud capture sensor, the captured point cloud sometimes depends on light and object material conditions.